# MySQL writing on a text file

Tags: mysql, macos, file-io, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to write data on a text file on MySQL workbench 5.2.45 in a Macbook Pro with Mountain Lion OS 10.8.2; and I get the following mistake:

"Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/Users/JohnnyDahdah/Desktop/datos2' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)   0.001 sec"

My code is the following:

```
select * from Datos into outfile '/Users/JohnnyDahdah/Desktop/datos2.txt';
```

Comment: What user does the mysql server run as?

Comment: @trojanfoe the main user

Comment: Sorry, who?  Unless the server is running as *you* then it does not have permission to write into your home directory.  You could probably arrange for *you* and *it* to share a group, but it's probably better to get it to write to `/tmp` and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe by the way, how do I put you helped me? I'm kinda noob here

Comment: I will post my comments as an answer and you can then accept it, if you wish.

Comment: I tested it in Ubuntu and it works just fine, but I can't make it work in windows XP, any suggestion @trojanfoe ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the server is running as *you* then it does not have permission to write into your home directory. You could probably arrange for *you* and *it* to share a group, but it's probably better to get it to write to `/tmp` and avoid the whole issue.

Comment: Details? This does not work by simply pointing to /tmp on MacOS. Same 'Access denied' error.